# How to filter request parameters based on user role in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, parameters, request, authorization, roles

I have an app that has admin, manager and employee roles.
A manager can edit fields A, B, C of all employees.
An admin can edit fields A, B, D, E of all users.

**Question:** How should I filter the parameters based on user role?

**Considerations:**

1. I don't want to filter the parameters inside the controller with an `if/else` clause because it feels so dirty.
2. There is an option to extend `FormRequest` class, but it's a hacky approach. The code ends up not very readable as `FormRequest` is never intended for manipulating request.
3. I can separate this logic into a private method inside the controller. It works, but there's still a fat controller.
4. I can separate the routes and controllers for admin, manager, and user. The code looks a lot simpler at the cost of a more complex structure.

What opinion do you guys have on this? Any other suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**-------------
Just a clarification since many are confused about what I am asking:

I am already doing authorization with `Policy` and `Gate`. What I am asking is about this specific case, when you want to update a user. A manager can update some certain fields (A, B, C) while an admin can update other fields (A, B, D, E).
Now we need to accept different request parameters according to user role, but where should we do this? In this controller, in an extended FormRequest class or in a separate controller?

Thanks!!!

Comment: you can use gates and policies `https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization` you can manage `route, controller, blade` based on Admin Roles

Comment: Have you considered a [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this video on Laracasts that I watched a long time ago but forgot. It gave me the exact answer that I needed.
Apparently creating a new controller and stick to the Laravel's CRUD conventions is the way to go.
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/20

Thank you all for spending time answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark maybe, but could you create a class for every role you have that has a constant that decides what fields are available to that specific role?

```
class AdminRole
{
    CONST EDITABLE_USER_FIELDS = [
        'name',
        'address',
        'phone',
        ...
    ];
}
```

and in your request:

```
$className = ucfirst($user->getRole()) . 'Role';

$fields = $className::EDITABLE_USER_FIELDS;

$data = $request->only($fields);
```

I didn't test this, but this should work as long as your class names are the same as the role names.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This's an approach that I've not thought of. Very interesting! One problem is about validation, as each field comes with its own validation. This Role class will need to contain that too. However, I'm not sure between this one and my approach of creating a separate controller which one will be better.

Comment: You could create a request for that, and get the same fields there. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/custom-validation-function-in-laravel-5 Maybe this can help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using same table say 'users' for storing data for admin, manager and employee. Make a new column say 'user_role'. Each user will be provided with 1, 2 and 3 for admin, manager and employee respectively. You just need to fetch 'user_role' from the table.

**Next**, you need to make generic function for role and pass the user_role into it.